# Asset Pipeline Breaking After Adding Spree to Rails App

Tags: ruby, rake, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline, spree

I am attempting to precompile my assets after adding the spree gem to my Rails 5 app. It was running fine before I added it, but now I can't get my assets to precompile.

application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootsy";
@import "theme";
@import "dropzone";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "spree/frontend/all";
@import "spree/backend/all";
@import "essentials";
@import "custom";
```

This is what I get with the rake assets:precompile command

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$navbar-height".
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spree_backend-3.3.0/app/assets/stylesheets/spree/backend/components/_sidebar.scss:3
```

Comment: There is probably a bootstrap variables file you are forgetting to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a conflict in the boostrap-sprockets call. Removing that import solved the issue.